# Splash screen on windows mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, splash-screen

Only that:

What is the best to do it?

I'm using C#, .Net Compact Framework 2.0 SP2, and Windows Mobile 5.0 and above.

I'm trying with a winForm but it takes long time to show. I want a splash screen that appear immediately (or as fast as possible).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have to overcome is that the CLR has to be JITTed at the start.  You can [use a managed Form for your splash screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc512460.aspx) but you have to pay the CLR JIT price before anything can be displayed, which can be a few seconds on many devices.  The best *from a perf standpoint) mechanism is to have a [separate native app that shows the splash screen](http://www.dotnetfordevices.com/article_detail.html?id=53) and in turn launches the managed app.

Comment: Second link is broken.